# RecyclerView won't refresh inside Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to populate a RecyclerView inside a fragment once I get an API response. I get the results, but they never appear on the screen.

[image]

What am I missing?

My MainActivity starts the following fragment:

```
// Generate API Client
val client = RestClient(endpoint, TimeoutType.LONG_TIMEOUT)

// Generate dialog
val dialog = AccessHistoryFragment.newInstance(client)
dialog.isCancelable = true
dialog.show(supportFragmentManager, AccessHistoryFragment::class.java.name)
```

Here is the code of Fragment:

```
class AccessHistoryFragment: DialogFragment()
{
    private lateinit var context: Context
    private lateinit var progressBar: ProgressBar
    private lateinit var noResultsTv: AppCompatTextView
    private lateinit var accessHistoryRv: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var adapter: AccessHistoryRecyclerViewAdapter
    private lateinit var client: RestClient
    private var elements = mutableListOf<Access>()

    companion object
    {
        fun newInstance(client: RestClient): AccessHistoryFragment
        {
            val fragment = AccessHistoryFragment()
            fragment.client = client
            return fragment
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog
    {
        // Get views
        val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_access_history, null) as View
        progressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.loading_bar) as ProgressBar
        accessHistoryRv = view.findViewById(R.id.access_history_rv) as RecyclerView
        noResultsTv = view.findViewById(R.id.no_results_tv) as AppCompatTextView
        context = view.context

        // Generate Recycler View
        generateRecyclerView()

        // Generate builder and title
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
        builder.setView(view)
        return builder.create()
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        cargarHistorial()
    }

    private fun generateRecyclerView()
    {
        try
        {
            adapter = AccessHistoryRecyclerViewAdapter(elements)
            accessHistoryRv.apply {
                this.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
                this.adapter = adapter
            }
        }
        catch (ex: Exception) { dismiss() }
    }

    private fun cargarHistorial()
    {
        Thread {
            try
            {
                val history = client.getAccessHistory(DateHelper.getCurrentDate())
                updateAccessHistory(history)
            }
            catch (ex: Exception) { dismiss() }
        }.start()
    }

    private fun updateAccessHistory(accessList: MutableList<Access>)
    {
        requireActivity().runOnUiThread {
            progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
            if (accessList.size > 0)
            {
                elements.addAll(accessList)
                adapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(0, accessList.size)
                accessHistoryRv.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
            else noResultsTv.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
    }
}
```

And finally the Adapter code:

```
class AccessHistoryRecyclerViewAdapter(private var elements: MutableList<Access>): RecyclerView.Adapter<AccessHistoryRecyclerViewAdapter.AccessHistoryViewHolder>()
{
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): AccessHistoryViewHolder
    {
        return AccessHistoryViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.access_item, parent, false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: AccessHistoryViewHolder, position: Int)
    {
        // Store current task
        holder.access = elements[position]

        // Init view elements
        holder.accessText.text = holder.access.toString()
    }

    // Return the size of your list
    override fun getItemCount() = elements.size

    inner class AccessHistoryViewHolder(v: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v)
    {
        var accessText: TextView = v.findViewById(R.id.access_text)
        lateinit var access: Access
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

With a ListView instead of a RecyclerView, it works correctly:

```
val accessHistoryLv = view.findViewById(R.id.access_history_lv) as ListView
val elements = accessList.map { elem -> elem.toString() }
val adapter = ArrayAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, elements)
accessHistoryLv.adapter = adapter
accessHistoryLv.visibility = View.VISIBLE
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be here

```
        holder.access = elements[position]
        holder.accessText.text = holder.access.toString()
```

replace it with this

```
 val element = elements[position]
 holder.accessText.text = element.example **
```

** Replace example with whatever your model Access contains